# Non-CS guy needs understanding on how threading works as it relates to multicore processors

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, computer-science

I do not have a computer science background. I have been learning java programming and wrote some hairy and bad programs that work. :-/ I'm one of the only few developers in the small company and I need to improve and write better programs. 
I have stumbled my way into the territory of multi-threading. At work, I hear people talk about how their computer processor has 4 cores or 8 cores etc. What does this mean? There is a black box there in my understanding of how a mulit-threaded programs behave on different hardware specs. So if I run a java program that fires 10 threads on a 4 core machine, how does that work? What are some of the things I need to be cautious of if I run the same program on an 8 core processor. Or a 2 core processor?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Read [thread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29) & [multi-core](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor) & [hyper-threading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading) wikipages

Comment: I did. Didn't understand. Can I have the explanation in laymen terms. Coz I'm truely a layman. Thanks.

Comment: This sort of general research is OT for a q&a site like SO. Multi threading is a big topic. I'd recommend reading book on the subject, and possibly even finding a course online or at your local college/adult learning center/whatever. For books, Java Concurrency In Practice is good, though it sounds like you may need additional resources.

Comment: If you have time and motivation, getting a better culture on computer science is always beneficial. You could even start with [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) and [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/) [Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_%28programming_language%29)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to answer precisely. You should benchmark if you want to optimize. Some **rules of thumb** (which have *exceptions*) :

- don't create a big lot of threads. More than many hundreds threads is almost always a mistake (on current desktop or ordinary server). Have only dozens of them.
- benchmark your application
- perhaps, make the number of threads somehow configurable (use a [thread pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern))
- when relevant, have a bit more threads than cores in your processor, especially for I/O bound applications.

A [multi-core processor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor) has several (parallel) [CPUs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit) or cores. Each core executes its own thread (or process, or task). So several threads are genuinely executed in parallel (simultaneously). Some processors are [hyper-threaded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threaded) (i.e. two register banks -etc...- sharing the same physical "core" giving the illusion of two "virtual" cores).

If you run a 10 thread Java program (with also 6 other non-threaded system "runnable" processes), the operating system kernel (e.g. your [linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel)) will have to [schedule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_%28computing%29) these 10+6=16 tasks (a task is either a thread in a multi-threaded process or a single-threaded process). The scheduler of the kernel will give each task a quantum of runtime on a core. After that quantum of time (e.g. some milliseconds), a new runnable task is rescheduled (on [preemptive multi-tasking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_%28computing%29) operating systems)

Read a good [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/operating_system/) on [operating system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) and about [processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29), [tasks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_%28computing%29) and [linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) or [unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix)...

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations. But can you tell me the answers to the questions I asked?

Comment: I tried to answer, but you really should read a good operating system book to understand. And understanding these things take time. Students in computer science or in software engineering need several years to grasp these concepts (and some of them fail to understand them properly).

Comment: Thank you. That's a wonderful explanation. I read on some topics you mentioned. Please add/correct me if I'm wrong. Atleast now I know not to run 100 threads on a single processor. A better idea would be to try 10 on a quadcore. I didn't know that a single CPU cannot run 2 threads at once. It can only allocate a tiny time slot to each of the multiple tasks it may be carrying out.